# How do I print the character ╔ (and other characters) using Unicode in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, unicode

I really need this for my homework. Here's my code:

```
int main() {
    printf("%c\n", 0x2554);
}
```

And it outputs to: T

I know it's such a simple question, but I've spent hours researching and trying to find the solution, but I couldn't get exactly what I need. I was actually told to do this using ASCII, but research tells me that it doesn't really work. So how do I print those weird characters using Unicode? Thanks.

Comment: Try `std::wcout << (wchar_t)0x2554`;`

Answer (score 0):

The `%c` format specifier is for 8-bit characters. `0x2554` is a 16-bit character. Use the `%lc` or `%C` format specifier for 16-bit characters.

```
int main() {
    printf("%lc\n", 0x2554);
}
```